# Nullpointer exception when drawing Rectangle2D array

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, drawrectangle

I have been trying to make an array of Rectangles to form a game grid and for some reason when the rectangles are supposed to be drawn i get several Nullpointer exceptions. I am not sure if this is to do with the way i am setting the x,y co-ords, width, height or something else completely.Through my testing it seems this has nothing to do with it however i might be wrong.

```
public class NewClass extends Frame {

    Rectangle2D[][] rectangelMatrix = new Rectangle[4][5];
    int width = 25;
    int height = 25;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    public NewClass() {
        setSize(1000, 1000);
    }

    public void arraysi() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rectangelMatrix.length; i++) {
            y = y + height;
            for (int j = 0; j < rectangelMatrix[i].length; j++) {
                x = x + width;
                rectangelMatrix[i][j] = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("hi");
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (int i = 0; i < rectangelMatrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rectangelMatrix[i].length; j++) {
                // EXCEPTION THROWN FROM LINE BELOW
                g2d.draw(rectangelMatrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void coolios() {
        repaint();
    }
}
```

The methods are called from tha main class as follows:

```
arraysi()
coolios()
```

EDIT: Here is the log -

```
exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:215)
at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Float.<init>(Path2D.java:190)
at sun.java2d.windows.GDIRenderer.doShape(GDIRenderer.java:204)
at sun.java2d.windows.GDIRenderer.draw(GDIRenderer.java:236)
at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.draw(ValidatePipe.java:136)
at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.draw(SunGraphics2D.java:2336)
at NewClass.paint(NewClass.java:64)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:248)
at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:224)
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(WComponentPeer.java:310)
at sun.awt.windows.WWindowPeer.handleEvent(WWindowPeer.java:695)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4706)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: ok, where is the nullpointerexception thrown?

Comment: Format your post first cause there is to much empty space

Comment: it seems your Graphics g parameter is null...

Comment: @XSen yeah i just noticed except i'm unsure of how to call the paint method in this case since i'm not really sending anything to G

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call

```
super.paint(g);
```

from you paint method.

Answer (score 0):

I test your frame class like below,it work without exception:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewClass frame = new NewClass();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.arraysi();
        frame.coolios();
}
```

I suggest you use Swing JFrame instead,but not use SWT Frame.
And you'd better put the rectangle drawing in a panel ,then add the panel to a frame.

Answer (score -3):

Im not sure but try making i and j both start from 1?
Could work.

Comment: Array indexes start from zero in Java.